# VS Code Default debuggin not working for nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Why VS Code Default debuggin not working for nodejs application?

Answer (score 2):

Its could be version related issue in launch.json.

I have chnage **"version": "0.2.0"** to **"version": "0.3.0"**. And that worked for me.